# Is Minecraft (PC) Controller-Friendly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, controllers

Am I able to use a controller to play the PC version of Minecraft? If so, can I just plug it in and play or do I have to do something else before being able use one?

Comment: I signed up for an account just to mention (though I can't reply with no reputation apparently), why are the two above mentions of the Steam method downvoted? Not only does it work, it is the easiest current method. Joypad/SplitScreen doesn't work for 1.12 (and requires modding), Windows 10 edition requires Windows 10, and Xpadder costs $10. The steam method is free (a steam account is free) adding it to steam is as simple as Games->Add a non-steam game to my library and the controller will work immediately, with a link on the right side to modify the controller layout if you prefer. You do no

Comment: how do I add a non steam game to my library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no built-in controller support on the PC version of Minecraft. You will need something like [Xpadder](http://xpadder.com/) to change each controller input to a keyboard/mouse input in order to use a controller.

Answer (score 14):

The Bedrock Edition of [Minecraft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/minecraft-windows-10-edition/9nblggh2jhxj) (formerly known as "Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition") supports multiple control schemes, including controllers and touchscreens. Just connect the controller to your PC and play.

Keep in mind that this version of Minecraft is not currently available on macOS (although the iOS/iPadOS version may be playable on Macs with M1 chip, starting with the late 2020 MacBook Air) or Linux, and has some differences compared to the Java version (aka. "Minecraft: Java Edition"). [It is possible to convert Java worlds into Bedrock worlds](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/guides/minecraft-rtx-world-conversion-guide/), but this is not officially supported. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: aka Bedrock? Is that version referred to here?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, when this question was originally posted in 2012, the "PC version" and the Java version were one and the same. The Windows 10 edition released 3 years later in 2015. Owners of the Java version were offered a free copy of the Windows 10 edition until 2018, 2 years after this answer was written. Even if it didn't address the Java version, I believe this answer is justified.

Comment: Thanks for the background. I wasn't criticizing the answer, just not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, the Windows 10 Edition was the Windows version of "Bedrock". Nowadays it is known simply as "Minecraft", while the original PC version has been renamed to "Minecraft: Java Edition" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks that is a useful clarification. Actually you might want to edit the answer just to update the terms or at least note what you said in the comment.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, good point. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

With a mod, yes. You can use the Minecraft Joypad/Split Screen Mod for actual analog movement (not just eight directions like with XPadder) and UI modifications for the controller (instead of only using an analog stick to emulate a mouse). It also creates the possibility of playing split screen with a friend (but you can use it just to play full screen single-player with a controller):
http://retro-hack.blogspot.com/p/minecraft-joypad-mod.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Linux, you may have luck with Joy2Key, found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/joy2key/

Debian package: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=joy2key

Ubuntu package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=joy2key

Another option is QJoyPad: http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/ which also claims mouse support.

I haven't tested these myself.

Comment: I've used these before and can confirm they work. Here's a quick rundown to use QJoyPad https://askubuntu.com/a/300873/159431

Answer (score 2):

I created an (open source) application called [PlusPad](https://github.com/KapitanH/PlusPad), specifically for use with *Minecraft: Java Edition*. It runs in the background and uses MonoGame to capture gamepad input to translate into Windows API calls for mouse and keyboard actions.

It runs on `Windows` and has been tested with Xbox 360 gamepads.

The simulated inputs are:

| Controller Input | Mapped to |
| --- | --- |
| Left Stick | WASD |
| Right Stick | Mouse movement |
| Back | F3 |
| Start | ESC |
| Back + Start | Enable/disable input |
| L3 | Ctrl |
| R3 | LShift |
| A | Space |
| B | Q |
| X | F5 |
| Y | E |
| LB | Mouse wheel up |
| RB | Mouse wheel down |
| LT | Mouse 2 |
| RT | Mouse 1 |
| DPad up | Text input - next character |
| DPad down | Text input - previous character |
| DPad left | Backspace |
| DPad right | Text input - accept character |

Answer (score 2):

you can use your xbox 360 controller and steam controller with steam. Just add the game to steam and choose the controller layout with 15 upvotes. In game swap the q and lshift buttons so you'll go down with red b button

Answer (score 2):

I use Mr.Crayfish's Controllable mod, Which Requires just plugging in a controller before launching minecraft. Made for 1.12.2 and download here: [Click me. link to offical website](https://mrcrayfish.com/mods?id=controllable)

Comment: By the way, Works only on windows 2000,Vista,XP,7,8.1,10 *Edit: Only works on Java Editon.

Comment: It also works on Mac and Linux. For 1.17 support, use LambdaControls (https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lambdacontrols).

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for everyone but its usefull for me if you have steam.
you can add the short cut to your library,change it to big picture,go to minecraft short cut,click game settings,then change the button scheme.Also be sure to have the driver software installed.