# Minecraft without a mouse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to play Minecraft with only a keyboard?

When I have free time I'm usually on my laptop. While I do have a mouse I can dig out, there's no surface to use it on. The touchpad is sort of ok, but I'd really much rather just map the mouse movement and button to the keys surrounding `L`, or whatever, and keep my hands in one position.

If it's relevant, OS is Win7.

Comment: You could also bring a gamepad/360 controller if you don't have a surface.

Comment: @SpellingD Minecraft doesn't support gamepads without modding it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There are many separate utilities that let you map gamepad input to keyboard/mouse input -- Minecraft doesn't have to directly support them to use them.

Comment: @SpellingD *I* know, but leaving an incomplete suggestion lying around is misleading. My reply is as much for the benefit of the poor reader who takes Minecraft and a gamepad with them (e.g.) on an airplane and then is confused why it doesn't work.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Fair enough. That's why I left it as a comment instead of a full-fledged answer.

Comment: @SpellingD You could just make it an answer. :) There is even [an existing question about using gamepads with MC](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/is-minecraft-pc-controller-friendly), which means you could just link to that instead of having to duplicate the work of listing all the possible utilities.

Answer (score 8):

Windows has a built-in way to control the mouse from the keyboard. It is very slow, though, and uses numpad buttons, which may be a problem on a laptop... Just in case: `Accessibility Options -> Mouse` or `Alt + Shift + Num Lock`.

Seriously, though, try [NeatMouse](http://neatdecisions.com/products/neatmouse/) or a similar tool.

Comment: Accessibility Options, I hadn't thought of that, thanks. This laptop (dell XPS) doesn't have a num-lock key, or anyway that I've been able to unearth to switch regular keys for numpad, (first one like this I've come across). So that's out. Neatmouse is headed in the right direction. It seems to be triggering extra ctrl presses somehow, so I haven't gotten it working yet; I haven't spent much time yet troubleshooting.

Comment: @mattwilkie Feel free to add another answer if you find anything better!

Comment: I turned on Mouse Keys but while this lets me move the mouse across the screen using the numeric keypad keys, it has absolutely no effect in Minecraft