# How can you make Minecraft behave like the XBox Version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play minecraft on PC, I have two accounts and I am giving one to my friend.

She loves minecraft but only plays on xbox at the moment, but I want to play with her and I refuse to play on xbox.

How can you make the PC version closer to the XBox version. I am specifically looking for controller support *and* an easy crafting method. like the example below
[image: Example]

Comment: @Caleb Not a duplicate - I specifically need it to be as close to xbox version as possible. there are many ways to incorporate a controller but not that i have found with the simplified crafting system that you have with xbox.

Comment: @Flaunting I have VTC'd just before reading your comment. I think it is a duplicate right now, since the questions is about playing MC with a controller. I will suggest an edit of the title in just a few minutes.

Comment: I hope that improves

Comment: I reccomend you incorporate a picture such as [this one](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120111024728/minecraft/images/a/a0/Xbox_Minecraft_Crafting_GUI.jpg) into your question, it will be more clear what you are trying to acomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Controller Support

The [question Caleb linked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/is-minecraft-pc-controller-friendly) shows several options for Controller support.

1. Use a program to map the Controller to Keyboard and Mouse presses, like [XPadder](http://xpadder.com/).
2. The [Minecraft Joypad/Splitscreen Mod](http://retro-hack.blogspot.ch/p/minecraft-joypad-mod.html) can also be used, and is far more integrated into the game (Tooltips and such). The XBox Gamepad is natively supported. Supports 1.6.4, 1.7.2 and 1.7.10 using Forge.

[image]

#### Crafting Grid

Looking around for a bit on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1qn85i/xbox_controller_support_on_pc/), your best bet seems to be [CJB's QuickCraft](http://cjbmods.com/mods/quickcraft/). I think you will still have to deal with moving a cursor with a gamepad, but at least there's no dragging items into the grid.

[image]

According to the website, the latest version is for MC 1.6.4, though [another site](http://minecraft-mods.org/quickcraft-mod/) lists it for 1.7.2/4 as well, so you might try it out (If you do, feel free to comment or edit the results into this answer).