# Can Minecraft on the PC be played with an Xbox One controller?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, controllers, xbox-one

I had figured that Minecraft had native Xbox One controller support, but found that I was wrong (at least as of January 19, 2016).

I've found resources that indicate that Minecraft can be played using the Xbox 360 controller with some help from other programs, but I'm unaware of any programs that claim to work with the Xbox One controller:

- [Is Minecraft (PC) Controller-Friendly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/is-minecraft-pc-controller-friendly)
- [How can you make Minecraft behave like the XBox Version](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176898/how-can-you-make-minecraft-behave-like-the-xbox-version)

Comment: You've seen the duplicate questions; I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly you're asking.  Is it controller friendly?  Software to make the controller work?  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Frank specifically asking if it's compatible with the Xbox One controller, not the Xbox 360 controller. Both of the other questions are well over a year old, and a lot can change in that time frame, and both seem to give answers specifically for the 360 controller.

Comment: Problem is, the question's already been asked.  Whether it was a day go or a year ago, we still have to keep all the answers together.  You're asking the same thing, so I've voted to close as a duplicate of the first question.  Do the answers not work for you or something in that question?

Comment: @Frank, you're right about the timing. I should have been more specific about the earlier questions. The possible duplicate you highlighted was asked before the Xbox One was released, so it must have been explicitly asking about the Xbox 360 controller, as specifying it being a 360 controller would add no further context. I'd suggest that it be edited.

Comment: I'm...not seeing any reference to any XBox controller at all in the question.  Are you?  All I'm seeing is a general question about controller support, so it should be applicable to all controllers, XBox or otherwise.  If you can get Windows to recognize it, then those answers should work for you, I believe.

Comment: It's possible, yes, but you will need an adapter and the answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/is-minecraft-pc-controller-friendly and it **doesn't** have native Xbox one support. Just because Microsoft bought MC, doesn't mean they make it fully Microsoft integrated. In fact, the same team works on it naw as before the purchase was even discussed.

Comment: @Frank that's a good point. It may have been too much of an assumption to think that the OP of that post was only thinking of controllers that natively support Minecraft on any system (which would only be the 360).